# Use TensorBoard to visualize graph from tf_agents

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, reinforcement-learning, dqn

I'm quite new to RL and currently teaching myself how to implement different algorithms and hyper-parameters using tf_agents library.

I've been playing around with the code provided from this tutorial https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/agents/blob/master/docs/tutorials/1_dqn_tutorial.ipynb.

After learning how to use TensorBoard I've come to wonder how I can visualize a graph from tf_agents library. Every TensorBoard tutorials/posts seems to implement its own model or define tf.function to log graph. However, I just can't apply such methods to the tutorial above.

If someone can help me visualize a model graph using tf_agents in TensorBoard, it will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider that this colab notebook is a very simple version of how TF-Agents actually works. In reality you should use the Driver to sample trajectories instead of you manually calling

```
agent.action(state)
env.step(action)
```

at every iteration. The other advantage of the Driver is that it provides easy compatibility with all the metrics in TF-Agents.

As to your question here is how:

At the beginning of your training define a summary_writer with something like:

```
train_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, 'train')    
train_summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(
            train_dir, flush_millis=10000)
train_summary_writer.set_as_default()
```

Now everytime you call agent.train it will flush to this summary writer and its tensorboard folder `train_dir`.

To add some metrics into the mix simply define them with something like:

```
train_metrics = [
        tf_metrics.NumberOfEpisodes(),
        tf_metrics.EnvironmentSteps(),
        tf_metrics.AverageReturnMetric(buffer_size=collect_episodes_per_epoch),
        tf_metrics.AverageEpisodeLengthMetric(buffer_size=collect_episodes_per_epoch),
    ]
```

Pass them to the Driver as observers together with your Replay Buffer like this:

```
dynamic_episode_driver.DynamicEpisodeDriver(
            tf_env,
            collect_policy,
            observers=replay_observer + train_metrics,
            num_episodes=collect_episodes_per_epoch).run()
```

And after this log them to your summaries with:

```
for train_metric in train_metrics:
    train_metric.tf_summaries(train_step=epoch_counter, step_metrics=train_metrics[:2])
```

In case you're wondering, the `step_metrics` arg is to plot the last two metrics against the first two.